# Book where girl is raised in history museum to believe she as actually part of the time period her exhibit is based on

Tags: story-identification

So, I remember being read a book in elementary school (so it was at least written by 97-98). It was about a girl in the 1700-1800's who found out she was actually part of an exhibit in a history museum - The entire younger generation thought they were actually in the time period, while all the adults were in on it. Could someone help me identify this story?

Comment: Please try to add anything that may help identification. What language was it in? What was the cover like? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Comment: Sounds like *The Prisoner* in reverse.

Comment: I'm happy to see you got the answer you were looking for, but was there anything about the story that made it SF or Fantasy?

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry, my elementary school teacher read the book to us as a class so I wracked my brain to come up with all I could about it. I'm pretty sure that Monica's answer is correct though

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I believe you're looking for *Running Out of Time*, by Margaret Peterson Haddix (1996). From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_Out_of_Time_(Haddix_novel)):

> Jessie Keyser is a 13-year-old girl from the village of Clifton, Indiana, in the 1840s. During a village-wide outbreak of diphtheria, Jessie's mother reveals it is actually 1996, and Clifton Village is a tourist attraction, a replica of a historical village. Her mother asks her to retrieve a cure for now her own sister Katie has taken ill; the owners of the attraction ceased to provide modern medical care to the villagers in order to preserve its authenticity. She tells Jessie to get the cure from a man named Isaac Neeley, who did not think Clifton should be a tourist attraction. Jessie's escape will be difficult, because Clifton is guarded to ensure that none of the villagers leaves or finds out it is actually 1996.

Comment: This has been on my to-read list for years.

Comment: So based on that description, did M. Night Shyamalan use this as the starting point for The Village?  Those are strikingly close parallels between the two stories.

Comment: @MikeClark That's been alleged but there was never a lawsuit. https://books.google.com/books?id=c8PnAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA41#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Thanks for the link @MissMonicaE.  I will definitely have to check this book out now.